# Burninate [selling-software] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

Should we burninate [selling-software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selling-software) tag? It currently has around 33% closed questions. There is no tag wiki for it. The concept is more appropriate for sales and marketing site instead of a site for professional and enthusiast programmers.

Comment: I went through and closed them all. I only saw one that was even moderately upvoted, so I don't think we'll be missing anything if we just delete them. I'll do that in a few days, once they go from on-hold to closed, so please don't remove the tags yet.

Comment: @BilltheLizard ... oops.

Comment: @Will Oh well. Not a big deal I guess. They'll get cleaned up by automated processes or the community eventually.

Comment: There were so few of them.. and so tasty...

Comment: @BilltheLizard In case you need those questions for deletion, added all the closed questions of [selling-software] tag in the answer below.

Comment: Thanks @AzizShaikh. I'll clean those up later today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tag has been burninated (thanks to Bill and Will). Following are all the closed questions earlier tagged as [selling-software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selling-software) which now may have to be deleted as [commented by Bill the Lizard♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268939/burninate-selling-software-tag#comment79188_268939):

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24899439/selling-userscripts-server-side-logic
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23334168/is-the-android-app-beta-test-not-free
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876246/creating-a-full-ios-framework-and-tracking-the-users-apps-and-devices-using-t
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649195/use-different-home-address-to-sing-up-for-google-checkout-in-order-to-sell-apps
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954308/which-platform-to-use-for-customer-access-to-software-with-maintenance-contracts
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13215081/how-much-security-do-i-need-for-the-first-release-of-a-desktop-app
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966937/gnu-agpl-v3-license-cloud-hosting-saas
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308102/google-check-out-what-do-i-need
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367467/custom-fields-for-the-prestashop-product-details-page
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464957/how-to-sell-android-apps-to-individuals-in-china
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806032/can-i-sell-a-website-that-uses-relies-on-the-libraries-under-the-lgpl-licence
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221670/how-do-themeforest-items-can-be-sold-with-gpl-licensing
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054446/which-right-should-i-sell-in-selling-an-android-app-to-a-telcom-company-to-pre-i
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349049/making-a-paid-application-for-android-market
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290518/what-is-a-good-ecommerce-software-to-use-for-my-website
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163085/selling-open-source
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004756/selling-a-company-how-to-let-the-buyer-safely-evaluate-the-source-code
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559623/best-way-to-charge-for-open-source-software
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238903/what-is-the-best-web-platform-to-sell-when-it-has-grown
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050891/selling-apps-as-a-private-individual-on-android-market
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949960/license-source-code-of-app
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877726/free-for-personal-use-license
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657545/where-a-developer-can-sell-donate-his-time
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250214/how-can-you-sell-or-auction-your-code

Comment: Thank you. This tag is now burned to the ground and its fields are sown with salt.

Comment: @BilltheLizard music to my ears :) Thank you.

Comment: Is there a StackExchange site where these sorts of question topics are on-topic?